# Detecting dependency collisions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

**Short version of the question:**

Is there a good way to detect at build time if I have any cases where 2 or more projects reference different versions of the same assembly?  (really, I would like to teach our CI server to do this)

**Long Version:**

So here's an interesting problem (simplified a bit for easy digestion):

Recently encountered a situation where we had 2 projects in a solution, A and B.  Both A and B depend upon a 3rd party nuget package C.

A always loads C, B only needs C in rare circumstances.

So, during this sprint, a developer updated Project A to use the latest version of the C package (not realizing that B also depended upon C)

Everything built and the tests that we had passed (we have insufficient test coverage), but when we released to production, we had failures occuring when B attempted to use the dependency (loader issues, because we wanted a different version of the strongly named assembly).

We found the problem, and corrected it, but.  I would really love to be able to catch this during development.  It would be even cooler if our build server could detect this (TFS 2012) when it does a CI build.

How might I go about detecting this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS can't do this for you because of the dynamic loading (unless I'm missing something): it just has no way of knowing which assemblies wil be loaded at runtime.

We had the same problem once (using Prism - all our assemblies are loaded at application startup normally, and the order is described in a config file though most are optional). I First thought of making a small tool that basically scans all packages.config or csproj files to see what assemblies are used in what version, and make it complain when two packages of different versions are found. But I ended up with dealing with it at a higher level, more direct and foolproof: we now have a simple class, sort of a stub of the actual application, that just loads all the application's components and modules as described in the config file. This results in all assemblies that can ever get loaded to be loaded so if something goes wrong it will be found. This functionality is simply placed in a unit test.

Comment: I like that suggestion.  I will definitely consider this.  The other direction I was moving in was to build a tool load the assemblies in the bin folder, call GetReferencedAssemblies() and search for cases where the file name is the same but version number is different (the tool would be run by the Build Server).  I like your solution though, so I'm going to have to consider it as well.  Thank you!